# Entity Framework deletion of non-null foreign keyed rows

Tags: entity-framework

I have a schema similar to the standard Product / OrderDetails / Order setup. I want to delete a single Product and cascade delete all OrderDetails which reference that product.

Assuming that I've thought this through from the business rules perspective, what's the most elegant way to handle that with Entity Framework 4?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't do `on delete cascade` in the db?

Comment: I was trying not to do that for other reasons, but I agree it's the best answer if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First thing is first:**

Is there any reason `on delete cascade` at the database level won't work?

**If that's really not a possibility, you could try the following:**

Since `ObjectContext` doesn't have a `DeleteAll` style method...you could always implement your own:

```
public static void DeleteAll(this ObjectContext context, 
    IEnumerable<Object> records)
{
    foreach(Object record in records)
    {
        context.DeleteObject(record);
    }
}
```

Then you could write something like (probably in a Repository):

```
context.DeleteAll(context.OrderDetails.Where(od => od.Product == product));
```

Or, to be a little cleaner:

```
var toDelete = context.OrderDetails.Where(od => od.Product == product);

context.DeleteAll(toDelete);
```

Comment: Your idea in comments is cleaner than your answer. :) The EF should notice the cascade and "just work." http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/08/19/tip-33-how-cascade-delete-really-works-in-ef.aspx

Comment: @Craig I only posted the answer because I didn't get any response to my comments. I'll update my post.

Comment: Thanks - I think the edit to use on delete cascade if possible, otherwise manually delete cascading relationships sums this up well.